# Django Bootstrap list

Tags: django

I have displayed some of models in a bootstrap tree. Now i have to display the details of a particular node of that tree in a bootstrap list. I know i need to use AJAX view for this. But I am not getting any clear idea. Please help me.

Following is my view

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = dict()
    organization = Organization.objects.all()
    orglocations = Orglocations.objects.all()
    locationprocessarea = Locationprocessarea.objects.all()
    processareaasset = Processareaasset.objects.all()
    processtaglink = Processareaassettaglink.objects.all()
    context["TreeStructure"] = [
        {
            'text': organizations.name,
            'nodes': [
                {
                    'text': orglocationss.name,
                    'nodes': [
                        {
                            'text': processarea.name,
                            'nodes': [
                                {
                                    'text': processasset.name,
                                    'nodes':[{
                                        'text':processareafilter.name,
                                        'nodes':[{
                                            'text':taglink.name
                                        }for taglink in processtaglink.filter(areaassetid=processareafilter.id)]
                                    }for processareafilter in processareaasset.filter(parentassetid=processasset.id)]
                                } for processasset in processareaasset.filter(processareaid=processarea.id).filter(parentassetid__isnull=True)]
                        } for processarea in locationprocessarea.filter(locationid=orglocationss.id)]
                } for orglocationss in orglocations.filter(organizationid_id=organizations.id)]
        } for organizations in organization.filter(id=1)]
    return {

        "tree_view": context
    }
```

and the script i have used in my template is,

```
<script>
var test_tree = {{ tree_view.TreeStructure | safe }};
$('#tree').treeview({data: test_tree});
</script>
```

Please help me..!! thanks in advance

Comment: Try `var test_tree = "{{ tree_view.TreeStructure | safe }}";`

Comment: @itzmeontv  Its showing error

Answer (score 0):

The `TreeStructure` variable is a list of python dictionaries, and the default `__str__` method does not produce valid JSON which is what you need to output for javascript to understand it. Try loading the page in your browser with the console open, I guarantee you'll see an error of some sort.

To prove it another way:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(str([{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

So do a `json.dumps()` on the data before printing it out in the template. The use of the `safe` filter is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. I am getting the perfect output for my code. Now my problem is i have to display a bootstrap list which contains the details of a particular node while clicking that node

Comment: Sounds like a completely different problem, probably should post a new question for it.

Comment: Is my question understandable??

Comment: Hey guys.. I got my answer.. Thanks for helping.. I used an ajax call to display the view